# Blender 2.8 video editing video becomes dark

Tags: blender, video-editing

All configurations are default, I have not changed anything, in the old version is correct, under is my screenshot:

This is a screenshot of Blender 2.8:

[image: blender 2.8 video editing]

And this is a screenshot of Blender 2.79:

[image: blender 2.79 video editing]

When I open the new project (created by Blender 2.8) in Blender 2.79, the video is dimmed too.

Comment: In the strip properties, there is a blend mode, in 2.80 it is under `Adjust->Compositing`. Check the blend mode and opacity value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Blender `2.80+` go to `Context: Render Menu` (Menu where cycles or Eevee can be selected), expand `Color Management` and set `View Transform` to `Standard` instead of `Filmic`. In my case it was set to Filmic by default and the rendered video looked dark gray instead of bright white.

**Settings shown in Blender-2.92**

[image]